# How to get average of all the columns and store into a new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 4 |

I need to compute the average of all the columns and need the dataframe looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| Average | 2 | 1.5 | 0.25 | 2.5 |

I'm trying this but it gives me error

```
df = df.append({'user_id':'Average', df.mean}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also working:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.mean().to_frame('Average').T])
```

which will create the following result.

```
           A    B     C    D
1        1.0  0.0  0.00  1.0
2        2.0  1.0  0.00  2.0
3        2.0  3.0  1.00  3.0
4        3.0  2.0  0.00  4.0
Average  2.0  1.5  0.25  2.5
```

#### Comment

If you really want to mix floats and integers, please use

```
pd.concat([df, df.mean().to_frame('Average', ).T.astype(object)])
```

This will result in

```
           A    B     C    D
1          1    0     0    1
2          2    1     0    2
3          2    3     1    3
4          3    2     0    4
Average  2.0  1.5  0.25  2.5
```

I want to quote from the [official documenation to `dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes) to show the disadvantage of this solution:

> Finally, arbitrary objects may be stored using the object dtype, but **should be avoided** to the extent possible (for performance and interoperability with other libraries and methods).

This is also the reason, why the default data type is `float`.

Comment: that is actually pretty nice, that way it always ends up at the bottom

Comment: This command also converts all the dataframe values into float values. I only need Average row to be float

Answer (score 2):

do you mean to do:

```
df.loc["Average", :] = df.mean()
```

this creates a new row called "Average" in your df where over all columns you store the mean over all columns

Comment: This command also converts all the dataframe values into float values. I only need Average row to be float

Comment: as  other people mentioned, you can only mix dtypes in columns if you use object as dtype, but that is not really efficient if you work with bigger datasets. Also that will limit the functions you can use on your columns.

Answer (score 2):

It will surely work :-

`df = pd.concat([df, df.mean().to_frame('Average').T])`

Comment: This is converting the whole dataframe to float values. I only need the average row to be in a floating number

Comment: Kindly asking, why are you posting allready existing solutions? This makes is difficult for users to search for the best solution in future?

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.describe()).loc[['mean']] ])

        A    B     C    D
0     1.0  0.0  0.00  1.0
1     2.0  1.0  0.00  2.0
2     2.0  3.0  1.00  3.0
3     3.0  2.0  0.00  4.0
mean  2.0  1.5  0.25  2.5
```

Comment: This command also converts all the dataframe values into float values. I only need Average row to be float

Comment: I want to mention that [`describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) calculates much more statistics than the PO was asking for. Therefor this could be ineffectiv.

Comment: Hi @HaseebSultan, Pandas column has the same `dtype`, unable to mix integers and float in the same column

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to add a line at the bottom :

```
df.loc['Average'] = df.iloc[:, :].mean()
```

##### >>> print(df)

[image]

Comment: As you can see, This is converting the whole dataframe to float values. I only need average row to be in a floating number